# wordpress woocommerce templates did not update?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have two sites, one sandbox and one live.

Woocommerce needs a core updates so I updated all the plugins, WordPress and Woocommerce.  In wp-admin->woocommerce->status on my sandbox under templates overrides I can see the files that needed manual update.  So I renamed the old files and copied over the new files from the plugins/woocommerce/templates folder.  WC->status shows the files have been updated to the latest ones.

I did the same behavior to the live site and WC->status still shows like the files have not been updated!?  The user permissions are correct, the site is fine and the updates all worked but WC->status still thinks I'm using the old templates and when I vim to view the files they all show they are the latest version. wtf?

is this cache?  Because I have purged cache and clear cache and cookies.  The sandbox and live are identical sites, yet live still thinks my old files are there.